# picamera on raspberry pi zero module not installed

Tags: python-3.x

SUMMARY:

Unable to run a time-lapse Python3 script due to a module not being installed. I am running Raspian Lite on Raspberry Pi Zero W.

THINGS I'VE TRIED:

I've tried installing picamera module for python. Tried googling the error and came across https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88339/importerror-no-module-named-picamera

Here is a list of installed modules. I can't see picamera on there??

> > > help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

BaseHTTPServer      aifc                httplib             sets
Bastion             antigravity         ihooks              sgmllib
CDROM               anydbm              imageop             sha
CGIHTTPServer       argparse            imaplib             shelve
Canvas              array               imghdr              shlex
ConfigParser        ast                 imp                 shutil
Cookie              asynchat            importlib           signal
DLFCN               asyncore            imputil             site
Dialog              atexit              inspect             sitecustomize
DocXMLRPCServer     audiodev            io                  smtpd
FileDialog          audioop             itertools           smtplib
FixTk               base64              json                sndhdr
HTMLParser          bdb                 keyword             socket
IN                  binascii            lib2to3             spwd
MimeWriter          binhex              linecache           sqlite3
Queue               bisect              linuxaudiodev       sre
RPi                 bsddb               locale              sre_compile
ScrolledText        bz2                 logging             sre_constants
SimpleDialog        cPickle             lsb_release         sre_parse
SimpleHTTPServer    cProfile            macpath             ssl
SimpleXMLRPCServer  cStringIO           macurl2path         stat
SocketServer        calendar            mailbox             statvfs
StringIO            cgi                 mailcap             string
TYPES               cgitb               markupbase          stringold
Tix                 chunk               marshal             stringprep
Tkconstants         cmath               math                strop
Tkdnd               cmd                 md5                 struct
Tkinter             code                mhlib               subprocess
UserDict            codecs              mimetools           sunau
UserList            codeop              mimetypes           sunaudio
UserString          collections         mimify              symbol
_LWPCookieJar       colorsys            mmap                symtable
_MozillaCookieJar   commands            modulefinder        sys
**builtin**         compileall          multifile           sysconfig
**future**          compiler            multiprocessing     syslog
_abcoll             contextlib          mutex               tabnanny
_ast                cookielib           netrc               tarfile
_bisect             copy                new                 telnetlib
_bsddb              copy_reg            nis                 tempfile
_codecs             crypt               nntplib             termios
_codecs_cn          csv                 ntpath              test
_codecs_hk          ctypes              nturl2path          textwrap
_codecs_iso2022     curses              numbers             this
_codecs_jp          datetime            opcode              thread
_codecs_kr          dbhash              operator            threading
_codecs_tw          dbm                 optparse            time
_collections        decimal             os                  timeit
_csv                difflib             os2emxpath          tkColorChooser
_ctypes             dircache            ossaudiodev         tkCommonDialog
_ctypes_test        dis                 parser              tkFileDialog
_curses             distutils           pdb                 tkFont
_curses_panel       dl                  pickle              tkMessageBox
_elementtree        doctest             pickletools         tkSimpleDialog
_functools          dumbdbm             pipes               toaiff
_hashlib            dummy_thread        pkgutil             token
_heapq              dummy_threading     platform            tokenize
_hotshot            email               plistlib            trace
_io                 encodings           popen2              traceback
_json               ensurepip           poplib              ttk
_locale             errno               posix               tty
_lsprof             exceptions          posixfile           turtle
_md5                fcntl               posixpath           types
_multibytecodec     filecmp             pprint              unicodedata
_multiprocessing    fileinput           profile             unittest
_osx_support        fnmatch             pstats              urllib
_pyio               formatter           pty                 urllib2
_random             fpformat            pwd                 urlparse
_sha                fractions           py_compile          user
_sha256             ftplib              pyclbr              uu
_sha512             functools           pydoc               uuid
_socket             future_builtins     pydoc_data          warnings
_sqlite3            gc                  pyexpat             wave
_sre                genericpath         quopri              weakref
_ssl                getopt              random              webbrowser
_strptime           getpass             re                  whichdb
_struct             gettext             readline            wsgiref
_symtable           glob                repr                xdrlib
_sysconfigdata      grp                 resource            xml
_sysconfigdata_nd   gzip                rexec               xmllib
_testcapi           hashlib             rfc822              xmlrpclib
_threading_local    heapq               rlcompleter         xxsubtype
_warnings           hmac                robotparser         zipfile
_weakref            hotshot             runpy               zipimport
_weakrefset         htmlentitydefs      sched               zlib
abc                 htmllib             select

CODE BELOW:

```
from time import sleep
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)

WAIT_TIME = 300

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
for filename in 
camera.capture_continuous('/home/pi/camera/img{timestamp:%H-%M-%S-%f}.jpg'):

sleep(WAIT_TIME)
```

The expected result is images to appear in the camera folder timestamped every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not stated in the documentation of picamera and it could be that its trying to run in python 2.

But I found the solution to be the following:

You need to have the following packages installed: *python-picamera & python3-picamera*

So running:
    **sudo apt-get install python-picamera** fixed it